# Mixed Integer Programming/Optimization using the Genetic Algorithm

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, knapsack

I am working with the R programming language. Given a data set ("my_data"), I am trying to use an mixed integer optimization algorithm (e.g. genetic algorithm) to find out which filters applied on which variables produces the smallest percentage of zero values (subject to some constraints).

**Part 1:** Here is the data I am using

```
set.seed(123)

num_var_1 <- abs(rnorm(1000, 10, 1))
num_var_2 <- abs(rnorm(1000, 10, 5))
num_var_3 <- abs(rnorm(1000, 10, 10))
num_var_4 <- abs(rnorm(1000, 10, 10))
num_var_5 <- abs(rnorm(1000, 10, 10))

factor_1 <- c("0","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("0","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("0","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("0","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("0","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

id = 1:1000

my_data = data.frame(id,num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)

#randomly add some zeros to the data
my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {
  x[sample(seq_along(x), length(x)/2)] <- 0
  x
})

 head(my_data)
  id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4 num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  1 10.357273 19.219814 27.031869   0.00000  3.865392            0           BB            0            0            0
2  2  0.000000  8.746435  0.000000   0.00000  1.047103            0            0          CCC            0            0
3  3  8.608149 10.192377  5.528652  11.39321 19.821561            0           BB            0            0         BBBB
4  0 11.555258 14.732870  8.651462  12.54166  0.000000            0           BB            0            0            0
5  5 10.125296  0.000000  8.095136   0.00000 31.131257            0            0            0         CCCC         EEEE
6  6  8.832702  9.877200  3.155799  16.06504 20.368927            0            0            0            0            0
```

**Part 2:** Here are the acceptable ranges for each of the variables

- num_var_1 has to be between range(num_var_1) : `7.029118 , 13.014451`
- num_var_2 has to be between range(num_var_2) : `0.0296502 ,  29.6070503`
- num_var_3 has to be between range(num_var_3) : `0.02422479 ,  46.72178885`
- num_var_4 has to be between range(num_var_4) : `0.03661167 ,  53.22815207`
- num_var_5 has to be between range(num_var_5) : `0.01581034 ,  41.22046108`
- factor_var_1 can take any of the following values (all possible combinations of levels) : `"none"      "0"         "B"         "C"         "0 & B"     "0 & C"     "B & C"     "0 & B & C"`
- factor_var_2 can take any of the following values (all possible combinations of levels): `"none"        "0"           "BB"          "CC"          "0 & BB"      "0 & CC"      "BB & CC"     "0 & BB & CC"`
- factor_var_3 can take any of the following values (all possible combinations of levels):

  `"none"                "0"                   "BBB"                 "CCC"                 "DDD"                 "0 & BBB"             "0 & CCC"             "0 & DDD"             "BBB & CCC"           "BBB & DDD"           "CCC & DDD"           "0 & BBB & CCC"       "0 & BBB & DDD"       "0 & CCC & DDD"       "BBB & CCC & DDD"     "0 & BBB & CCC & DDD"`
- factor_var_4 and factor_var_5 can take any of the following values (all possible combinations of levels):

  `"none"                          "0"                             "BBBB"                          "CCCC"                          "DDDD"                          "EEEE"                          "0 & BBBB"                      "0 & CCCC"                      "0 & DDDD"                      "0 & EEEE"                      "BBBB & CCCC"                   "BBBB & DDDD"                   "BBBB & EEEE"                   "CCCC & DDDD"                   "CCCC & EEEE"                   "DDDD & EEEE"                   "0 & BBBB & CCCC"               "0 & BBBB & DDDD"               "0 & BBBB & EEEE"               "0 & CCCC & DDDD"               "0 & CCCC & EEEE"               "0 & DDDD & EEEE"               "BBBB & CCCC & DDDD"            "BBBB & CCCC & EEEE"            "BBBB & DDDD & EEEE"            "CCCC & DDDD & EEEE"            "0 & BBBB & CCCC & DDDD"        "0 & BBBB & CCCC & EEEE"        "0 & BBBB & DDDD & EEEE"        "0 & CCCC & DDDD & EEEE"        "BBBB & CCCC & DDDD & EEEE"     "0 & BBBB & CCCC & DDDD & EEEE"`

**Part 3:** This is the function ("f") I am trying to optimize - this function takes 10 inputs (filters for each of the 10 variables in "my_data"), creates a new data set according to the specified filters, and then returns the overall percentage of zeros in the data set:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) {

target1 = x1
target2 = x2
target3 = x3
target4 = x4
target5 = x5
target6 = x6
target7 = x7
target8 = x8
target9 = x9
target10 = x10

result <-  filter(my_data[,-1], num_var_1 < target1 & num_var_2 < target2 & num_var_3 < target3 & num_var_4 <target4 & num_var_5 <target5 & 
factor_var_1 %in% target6 & factor_var_2 %in% target7 & factor_var_3 %in% target8 & factor_var_4 %in% target9 & factor_var_5 %in% target10)
s = sum(result == '0', na.rm = TRUE) / prod(dim(result)) * 100
return(1 - s)


}
```

As an example, we test to see if this function runs:

```
 f(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "0", "0", "0", c("CCCC","EEEE"), "EEEE")



[1] 63.63636
```

**My Question:** Can someone please show me how to use an optimization algorithm to optimize the function "f"? In the past, I usually used the "GA" library in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html) for optimizing functions where all variables can only take numerical outputs.

If I only had to deal with numerical inputs, I could optimize a modified version of the function "f" using the GA library in R:

```
#modified version of "f" with only numerical inputs

f_mod <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) {
    
    target1 = x1
    target2 = x2
    target3 = x3
    target4 = x4
    target5 = x5
    
    
    result <-  filter(my_data[,-1], num_var_1 < target1 & num_var_2 < target2 & num_var_3 < target3 & num_var_4 <target4 & num_var_5 <target5 )
    s = sum(result == '0', na.rm = TRUE) / prod(dim(result)) 
    return(1 - s )
    
}

library(GA)

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  f_mod(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]),
         lower = c( min(num_var_1),  min(num_var_2),  min(num_var_3),  min(num_var_4),  min(num_var_5)), upper = c( max(num_var_1),  max(num_var_2),  max(num_var_3),  max(num_var_4),  max(num_var_5)), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 100, run = 100)


# results of the 100 iterations:

GA | iter = 1 | Mean = 65.58077 | Best = 75.30529
GA | iter = 2 | Mean = 66.92623 | Best = 75.30529

....

GA | iter = 99 | Mean = 79.04933 | Best = 80.62201
GA | iter = 100 | Mean = 79.08810 | Best = 80.62201

#view final solution

 GA@solution

           x1       x2        x3       x4        x5
[1,] 7.624509 3.220958 0.3176768 2.287231 0.5194747
[2,] 7.625705 3.235704 0.3180106 2.307864 0.5196744

GA@fitnessValue

[1] 80.62201
```

**But I do not know how I can write the above optimization algorithm to accommodate a function with numerical inputs and factor inputs.**

**Can someone please show me how to optimize the original function "f" using some optimization package in R (e.g. lpsolve, nloptr)?**

**Extra 1:** Visualizing the Optimization Algorithm's Progress

```
plot(GA, main = "Results of Optimization on f_mod")
```

[image]

**Extra 2:** Code to Obtain All Factor Levels:

```
factor_1 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_2 <- c("B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1")

factor_var_1 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

my_data = data.frame(factor_var_1, factor_var_2)

fac4 = levels(my_data$factor_var_1)
fac5 = levels(my_data$factor_var_2)
   
my_list = list(fac1, fac2)



st1 <- lapply(my_list, function(x) c("none", unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(x)), function(i) combn(x, i, FUN = paste, collapse = " & ")))));

#view answer

 st1

[[1]]
[1] "none"      "0"         "B"         "C"         "0 & B"     "0 & C"     "B & C"     "0 & B & C"
```

Comment: First, it would help if your sample R code used a seed for the random number generator, so that it is reproducible. When I run the data generator, I get different data, so I cannot compare to your "f" function. Second, your GA example will maximize the percentage of zeros, not minimize it. Third, you are counting zeros in the "id" column. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @ prubin: Thank you so much for your comments! I made some changes - thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the presence of "none" as a filter option. If that were selected for any factor, wouldn't you wind up selecting zero rows from the data set (making your percent zeros measure undefined)?

Comment: Also, I think you want your corrected function f to return 100 - s, not 1 - s, since s is a percentage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible (but a bit tricky) to write a mixed-integer linear program for this problem. If you are willing to accept a good but not guaranteed optimal solution, though, the GA is easily modified to handle it. The key is to use a chromosome of 10 real values, where the sixth through tenth are rounded down to the next lower integer and used to index a filter value for each factor variable from a list of all possible filter values.

I modified your code above to demonstrate this. In doing so, I corrected the output of the f function to be 100-s rather than 1-s, and also did away with the "none" option for each factor variable (which, if selected, results in no rows being chosen by the filter). You can see the results (and if desired extract the code) in this [notebook file](https://rubin.msu.domains/code/filter.nb.html).

Comment: @ prubin: I can not thank you enough for all the work you have done!

Comment: I had a few questions that I wanted to ask  - I am currently reviewing the code you have provided and trying to better understand it. I am learning so much - thank you!

Comment: If you don't think the questions will be of general interest to other people reading this question, you can always start a "chat" with me using the chat link in the page footer.

Comment: @stats555 I can

Comment: Happy New Year Everyone! I am still working on understanding the code - thanks!

Comment: @ Prubin : here are the points I wanted to add

Comment: 1) I figured out a way to add "constraints" to the function "f". This way, you can instruct the genetic algorithm to return a minimum number of rows from the original data set. If you are interested, would you like to see the this?

Comment: 2) Currently, I am working on a way to adapt your code into a "2 layer" process. After the genetic algorithm produces the first filter (i.e. GA@Solution[1,]) : all rows from the original data that math the first filter are removed, and the genetic algorithm then searches the data again for a second filter. The final fitness function will use the "average missing rate" from both filters. Of course, you could just run the genetic algorithm once, remove rows that match the first filter, and run the genetic algorithm again, but this will be "greedy search". Would you like to see it?

Comment: 3) Finally, I would like to ask your opinion - what do you think of this idea? When you have large datasets, it's very possible that certain groups of individuals (based on conditions using the rows/columns of the dataset) can have "smaller missing data rates" compared to the entire data set. Thus, it might be easier to model subsets of the data where the "missing data rates" are lower - however, I could not find any standard statistics/ML/AI algorithms to target this problem. What do you think of this methodology that involves evolutionary algorithms to search the data for these subsets?

Comment: If you are curious, this was the original question I had which lead to me all this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557978/identifying-cohorts-with-conditionally-low-non-response-rates

Comment: First off, you are very welcome. Thanks for offering to share your code, but no need. I can understand how you did it just from the verbal descriptions. As far as my opinion, I don't really have one. Dealing with missing data without biasing the results of the analysis is a tricky business at best. Also, I suspect that how to do it may depend on what specific analysis you are attempting (meaning in some cases skipping partial records might work, in other cases guesstimating the missing responses might be better, etc.).